# mac osx web server starting

Tags: macos

I have mac osx server (10.7).  I started web sharing.  Tried to hit home page.  Said no permission to go to /.  So I found the httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2, edited it (that took a while) to make DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents

Still no permission. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that your httpd.conf file was not already set to `/Library/WebServer/Documents` as that's the Apache default ...

Anyway, have you restarted Web Sharing since you made the change? Apache will not pick up changes to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf until you restart the service (or HUP the process).